# Grafana: на шкале TimeScale необходимо выделить цветом отдельные часы. Не получается при помощи аннотаций

Tags: аннотации, grafana

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы на графике автоматически помечались другим цветом определённые часы. Что-бы выглядело примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это делать в ручную (ctrl+клик), то да, получается, но хочется чтобы они выделялись автоматически. Как я понял это делается через настройки -> аннтоции. При попытке добавить свою аннотацию с запросом, выводит "No events found). Учитался в документацию, но так не понятно как выполнить мою задачу. Прошу помощи..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос в случае источника данных MySQL должен выводить данные в формате содержащем следующие ключи: time,timeEnd,title,text,tags и id, где:

- time - время в формате timeunix, начало отображения аннотации
- timeEnd - время в формате timeunix, конец отображения аннотации
- title - заголовок аннотации
- text - пояснение нотации
- tags - присваиваемый аннотации тэг (для того чтобы можно было пометить разными цветами)
- id - идентификатор дашбоарда для вывода аннотаций.

В общем случае самый простой запрос может быть например таким:

```
select 1705902720000 as time,1705929060000 as timeEnd,'Заголовок' as title,'Это день' as text,'daywork' as tags,1 as id
```

В этом случае отображно может быть что-то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]